# Get the same effect of the leipzig commands with the typgloss package

Tags: leipzig, gloss

A package was developed by Thomas Pellard [enter link description here](https://github.com/tpellard/typgloss) to convert grammatical glosses from uppercase into small capitals. But while this has the advantage of having those grammatical glosses in small capitals similarly to what the leizig commands do, we cannot get a list of the abbreviations of those grammatical glosses in the end of the document. I was wondering whether we could get that works without a need of having leipzig commands.

For instance, I would like to have this result : [image]

With this code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{typgloss}
\usepackage{leipzig}
\makeglossaries



\begin{document}


\ex. \gll cew wee \\
 woman.DEF DEM \\
\glt To the woman.\\
\mbox{}\\

\printglosses



\end{document}
```

Instead of this one:

```
\ex. \gll cew wee \\
 woman.\Def{} \Dem{} \\
\glt To the woman.\\
\mbox{}\\

\printglosses
```

Comment: The simple answer is no. They are designed to do very different things. `typegloss` just makes typing easier; `leipzig` actually creates a glossary for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since both packages are compatible, I think what I can do for the moment is to use once a leipzig command for each grammatical gloss in the document so that I can have it in the glossary. For the remaining time, just leave them in uppercase so that the package typgloss will print them in small caps.

Comment: Yes, that's what the author of `typegloss` intended, I think.  Unrelated, but you're not using `linguex` as intended. The \\ should be only used to at end of the language line and the gloss line. You have extra \\ after the translation line, and the `\mbox{}` is doing nothing as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes. In fact, there is a command that intended to enclose the text of the gloss between single quotes. That one will enclose anything within single quotes until it reaches a delimiter. I chose \\ as the delimiter, that is why I have the habit to put the \\ at the end of that line. It is just a simple habit.